# Socket-io-client issue with Electron main process

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron

Is it possible to connect to a socket-io server from the main-process in Electron ?

Since 'window' is not defined in the main-process i can't find any turnaround.

I'm using version 2.3.0.

I tried using socket-io-client on the main process side and got the following error after bundling and opening the electron app.

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

PS: I also tried updating to latest version and still got the same issue.

Comment: yes, it is possible.  Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.